# Integral involved trigonometric funtions

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I try to find closed form solution or approximate function to the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int \!{\frac {{x}^{2} \cos^{2} \left( x \right) 
 +x\sin \left( x \right) \cos \left( x \right) +1}{{x}^{4}
 \cos^{2} \left( x \right)+{x}^{2}\sin \left( x
 \right) \cos \left( x \right) +{x}^{6}+1}}\,{\rm d}x
\end{equation}
but it seems very difficult! Any hints?

Comment: Looks difficult. Easy to integrate numerically. The integrand is small outside $(-2,2)$.

Comment: I tried with some symbolic program like Maple, mathematica but it did not work.

Comment: i think we can not get a solution in the known elementary functions see the Rish algorithm

Comment: May I ask where you found the monster ?